# nginx reverse proxy http redirect to https, different ports

Tags: nginx, https, reverse-proxy

Say I have 2 different apps on the same website, but running on different ports.

odoo on port 8069
portainer on port 9443

My nginx config file:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    include snippets/self-signed.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

        root /var/www/html;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name _;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    include snippets/self-signed.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;
    server_name odoo.localhost;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8069; #If I put https here, and in browser also enter https, it actually will not work
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    include snippets/self-signed.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;
    server_name portainer.localhost;

    location / {
        proxy_pass https://localhost:9443;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name localhost;

    return 302 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

In browser, if I enter http://odoo.localhost, it will get redirected to https://odoo.localhost, and will NOT get passed to localhost:8069
Is there a way to only have 1 server entry for http to https redirect, and also able to send it to a specific port?

In this example, instead of adding two more server blocks:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name odoo.localhost;

    location / {
        proxy_pass https://localhost:8069;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name portainer.localhost;

    location / {
        proxy_pass https://localhost:9443;
        }
}
```

Is there a way to have only 1 server block to do the job of these two?
I might eventually end up with say 6 apps, and having to add/update 6 server blocks for http, and 6 blocks for https, seems to be redundant.

Also, why "proxy_pass https://localhost:8069" not work, but proxy_pass https://localhost:9443 works?

--===========================
Also tried "Said Gourida"s suggestion, with this config file, I am getting warning "nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "localhost" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored", and it doesn't work at all.

```
upstream odoo {
    server 127.0.0.1:8069;
}

upstream portainer {
    server 127.0.0.1:9443;
}

#odoo
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    return 301 https://localhost$request_uri;
    
    # Add Headers for odoo proxy mode
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host localhost;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

    location / {
         proxy_redirect off;
         proxy_pass http://odoo;
    }

    if ($host = localhost) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } 

}

#portainer
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    return 301 https://localhost$request_uri;
    
    # Add Headers for portainer proxy mode
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host localhost;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

    location / {
         proxy_redirect off;
         proxy_pass http://portainer;
    }

    if ($host = localhost) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } 

}

server {
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    server_name localhost;
    include snippets/self-signed.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try like this, and don't forget to add modifications for app2

```
#server 1
upstream odoo1 {
    server 127.0.0.1:8069;
}
#server 2
upstream odoo2 {
    server 127.0.0.1:8070;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
    
    # Add Headers for odoo proxy mode
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host www.example.com;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

    location / {
         proxy_redirect off;
         proxy_pass http://odoo1;
    }

    if ($host = www.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } 

    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } 

}

server {
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    # add here your ssl_certificate path
    #
    #
    #
}
```

Comment: Does not work.
Getting warning "nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "localhost" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored". I have added the complete config file to the original post.

Comment: no you need to add your config on it, like which ports you running servers ....etc